# How can I retrieve the data from a bluetooth device?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, device-driver

I have a bluetooth device, in particular a Heart Rate Measurement.

The bluetooth standard for these kind of device is the 180D 2A37.

This is the link: https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/characteristics/Pages/CharacteristicViewer.aspx?u=org.bluetooth.characteristic.heart_rate_measurement.xml

I would like to get the measurements. How can I do?

At the moment, I am able to connect and pair with my device using the Bluetooth API (`BluetoothSocket`)

Comment: Start with this documentation http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html if you want create app for android and than find some sample https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothChat and then modify for your purpose.

Comment: Thanks Majkl. I read the documentation and, at the moment, I am able to connect and pair to my device.
Is there a tutorial to read the data from the heart rate device?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not known. Generally, the communication should be the same and you need gain some experience with bluetooth communication. And then modify your project with some set properties by the manufacturer of your device.

Answer (score 1):

First, follow the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html) to setup blutooth API and get an instance of [`BluetoothSocket`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothSocket.html). This socket can be used to read and write bit data.

The chart you have mentioned explain the structure of 1 byte packets that the sensor uses. So, you can start reading bytes off the socket and de-code each byte using reference chart to get data.